# Should REST API returns error 400 on request that should not have query?

Tags: api, rest, http

Is there any standard in HTTP regarding how request should be handled in case where an endpoint/request URL that supposed to not receive any query but the requester supply a query anyway ?

if it exist, what the standard states ? if not, is there any other related standard/statement regarding this like how request query supposed to be handled in general or such within the HTTP standard ?

thank you

Comment: Normally the part of parameters which are not expected is just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you receive more parameters than expected and if you don't need it, you don't care

Comment: Yes, but how if the said parameter is a required one, for example, an 'id' number. When it's expected to be exist but only one yet the client supply query like this "/?id=10&id=11", how such case should be handled ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any standard in HTTP regarding how request should be handled in case where an endpoint/request URL that supposed to not receive any query but the requester supply a query anyway ?

From the perspective of HTTP, the entire target-uri in the request line is the identifier for the resource:

```
POST /123?456
```

In this example, the target-uri is `/123?456`.

RFC 7231 defines [404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Which is to say, if you want to draw the clients attention to the spelling of the target-uri, `404 Not Found` is the way to do that.

That said, there are no "rules" about how the server interprets the target-uri.  If you want to ignore the query part, and provide the same representation that is used for `/123` then that's *fine*.

> when you receive more parameters than expected and if you don't need it, you don't care

In messaging, ignoring unrecognized parts of the message can be useful when trying to ensure that your schema is forwards/backwards compatible; old clients using the old specification can talk to new servers using the new specification, and vice versa.

The same principle is described in the [header specification for HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.1)

> Other recipients SHOULD ignore unrecognized header fields.  These requirements allow HTTP's functionality to be enhanced without requiring prior update of deployed intermediaries.

Comment: so, if the server expect only one 'id', for example, then the request is /?id=10&id=12 we can just throw 404 ?

Comment: Yes.  We can also throw a bunch of caching meta-data into the response, so that intermediate components can handle that for us.  If we need to provide a more detail explanation for the client, that goes into the response message-body